# @media image fails to load on reduced screen

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries

I have a similar issue to one of my previous questions.
when i reduce to below 975px my picture should change to a differet jpg
it seems to work locally when i redue the size of the screen but when i check on online the new image doesnt show.

As this happened previously i played with it for several hours first for fear of looking stupid, but i give up now, ill take it on the chin if any one can assist:)

**HTML:**

```
<!-- load this image on big screen -->
<div class=" jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbotronbrejos hideformob">
    <div class="container-fluid relspan">
        <img class="brejosimg" src="resources\images\brejosHouse.jpg">
            <div class="jumbospan">
                <h4 id="fontI">Albufeira, Algarve Portugal</h4> 
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- load this image on smaller screens   -->
<div class="container-fluid navpad">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="farmhouseimg farmhouse"></div>
    </div>
</div>  <!-- end of container -->
```

**CSS:**

```
/* on screens that are less than 975px */

.farmhouseimg {
    background-image: url("../images/farmhouse.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width:100%;
    display: none;
    min-height: 600px;
}

.farmhouse {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    min-height: 600px;
    width:100%
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 975px) {

    .farmhouseimg {
        display: block;
    }
}

.hideformob {
    display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 975px) {
    .hideformob {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the other image in your media query?

Comment: ah forgot that updated now

Comment: When I put your code in [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/okLhnd1x/2/), it seems to work as desired. So can you produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: https://elfranco91.github.io/QDB/ here is the github link it doesnt show on mobile

Comment: @elfranco91 There is no image at https://elfranco91.github.io/QDB/resources/images/farmhouse.jpg (results in a 404).

Comment: sorted, thanks for pointing me in the right direction should have had a capital letters on img name FarmHouse.jpg.....schoolboy error:)